# How to have two Neo4j edition in one computer (Community and Enterprise)

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I first installed and configured Neo4j Enterprise edition on my Computer with windows 10 operating system and then installed and configured Community edition on my computer.
How can I switch between these two edition on the browser??
When I connect to localhost:7474\browser which one of the edition I can see?? and how can I configure that?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of Neo4j on the same machine, you just have to make sure they are listening on different ports. Specifically, you'll need to set `dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address` and `dbms.connector.http.listen_address` (this is the port you connect to to access Neo4j Broswer) to be different on each instance you want to run. The default is:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
```

These settings are available in `neo4j.conf`

Comment: Thanks. How can I set a different port? I mean which port should I assign to community edition?

Comment: Any high number port that isn't in use should be fine (for example, 8000 for bolt and 8001 for http)

Comment: I did what you said but I have problem connecting the the server :(